# Python expecting expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not StringVar

Tags: python, tkinter

Okay, so I'm working on a project that monitors two selected folders and automatically moves files created or edited within the last twenty-four hours from Folder_A to Folder_B.  It also will check the two folders manually when the user clicks the scan button.  So far it will select the two folders, but when I click the scan button I get this error.  How would I go about fixing the error? My code is below the error.  Please be understanding that I am still really new to python, so there might be quite a few really stupid mistakes in here.

```
 File 
"C:\Users\--\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Projects\File_transfer.py", line 63, in <module>
   scan_btn=Button(text="Scan", command = submitFunction())
 File "C:\Users\--\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Projects\File_transfer.py", line 34, in submitFunction
   for root, dirs,files in os.walk(origin_path):
 File "C:\Users\quirk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\os.py", line 342, in walk
   return _walk(fspath(top), topdown, onerror, followlinks)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not StringVar
```

My code for the project:

```
import tkinter
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import os,time
import datetime
import shutil
import datetime as dt

def browse_button():
    # Allow user to select a directory and store it in global var
    # called origin_path
    global origin_path
    filename = filedialog.askdirectory()
    origin_path.set(filename)
    print(filename)

def browse_button2():
    # Allow user to select a directory and store it in global var
    # called receiving_path
    global receiving_path
    filename = filedialog.askdirectory()
    receiving_path.set(filename)
    print(filename)

def submitFunction() :
    for root, dirs,files in os.walk(origin_path):
        for fname in files:
            path = os.path.join(root, fname)
            st = os.stat(path)
            mtime = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(st.st_mtime)
            shutil.move(path, dest)
    print('Submit button is clicked.')

root = Tk()
origin_path = StringVar()
receiving_path = StringVar()

#First Browse Button Label
lbl1 = Label(master=root,textvariable=origin_path)
lbl1.grid(row=0, column=1)
#Second Browse Button Label
lbl1_2 = Label(master=root,textvariable=receiving_path)
lbl1_2.grid(row=1, column=1)

lbl1_3 = Label(master=root)
lbl1_3.grid(row=2, column=1)

button = Button(text="Browse", command=browse_button)
button.grid(row=0, column=3)

button2 = Button(text="Browse", command=browse_button2)
button2.grid(row=1, column=3)

scan_btn=Button(text="Scan", command = lambda:submitFunction())
scan_btn.grid(row=2, column=7)

mainloop()

now = dt.datetime.now()
ago = now-dt.timedelta(hours=24)
strftime = "%H:%M %m/%d/%Y"
created = 'origin_path'
dest = 'receiving_path'
file_path = 'file:///'+os.getcwd()+'/' + ''

print("Last modified: %s" % time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(file_path)))
print("Created: %s" % time.ctime(os.path.getctime(file_path)))

for root, dirs,files in os.walk(origin_path):  
    for fname in files:
        path = os.path.join(root, fname)
        st = os.stat(path)    
        mtime = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(st.st_mtime)
        if mtime > ago:
            print("True:  ", fname, " at ", mtime.strftime("%H:%M %m/%d/%Y"))
            shutil.move(path, dest)

def find_info(): #this first func. works fine.for root, dirs, files in os.walk(created):
    for root, dirs, files in os,walk(origin_path):
        for fname in files:
            path = os.path.join(root, fname)
            st = os.stat(path)
            mtime = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(st.st_mtime)                          
    if mtime > ago:
        print(True)
    else:
        print(False)

print (find_info())                           
print (move())                               

print (os.listdir(dest))
print (os.listdir(created))
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are calling [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) with a tkinter [StringVar](https://www.askpython.com/python-modules/tkinter/stringvar-with-examples), but os.walk does not accept StringVars; it only accepts objects of type str, bytes, or os.PathLike (e.g. [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib) Path objects).

You can fix the error by using `os.walk(origin_path.get())` instead of `os.walk(origin_path)`. This gets the string from the StringVar and passes that to os.walk, instead of passing the StringVar to os.walk directly.

Comment: Thank you so much!  That was bothering me big time