# Expecting string, bytes, or os.PathLike or integer, not StringVar

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working on a project that monitors two selected folders and automatically moves files created or edited within the last twenty-four hours from `Folder_A` to `Folder_B`. It also will check the two folders manually when the user clicks the scan button. So far it will select the two folders, but when I click the scan button I get this error. How would I go about fixing the error?

My code is below the error. Please be understanding that I am still really new to python, so there might be quite a few really stupid mistakes in here.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import os,time
import datetime
import shutil
import datetime as dt



def browse_button():
  # Allow user to select a directory and store it in global var
  # called origin_path
  global origin_path
  filename = filedialog.askdirectory()
  origin_path.set(filename)
  print(filename)

def browse_button2():
  # Allow user to select a directory and store it in global var
  # called receiving_path
  global receiving_path
  filename = filedialog.askdirectory()
  receiving_path.set(filename)
  print(filename)

def submitFunction() :
  for root, dirs,files in os.walk(origin_path.get()):
      for fname in files:
          path = os.path.join(fname, root)
          st = os.stat(path)
          mtime = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(st.st_mtime)
          shutil.move(path, receiving_path)
  print('Submit button is clicked.')


root = Tk()
origin_path = StringVar()
receiving_path = StringVar()

#First Browse Button Label
lbl1 = Label(master=root,textvariable=origin_path)
lbl1.grid(row=0, column=1)
#Second Browse Button Label
lbl1_2 = Label(master=root,textvariable=receiving_path)
lbl1_2.grid(row=1, column=1)

lbl1_3 = Label(master=root)
lbl1_3.grid(row=2, column=1)

button = Button(text="Browse", command=browse_button)
button.grid(row=0, column=3)

button2 = Button(text="Browse", command=browse_button2)
button2.grid(row=1, column=3)

scan_btn=Button(text="Scan", command = lambda:submitFunction())
scan_btn.grid(row=2, column=7)

mainloop()

now = dt.datetime.now()
ago = now-dt.timedelta(hours=24)
strftime = "%H:%M %m/%d/%Y"
created = 'origin_path'
dest = 'receiving_path'
file_path = 'file:///'+os.getcwd()+'/' + ''

print("Last modified: %s" % time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(file_path)))
print("Created: %s" % time.ctime(os.path.getctime(file_path)))

for root, dirs,files in os.walk(origin_path.get()):  
  for fname in files:
      path = os.path.join(root, fname)
      st = os.stat(path)    
      mtime = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(st.st_mtime)
      if mtime > ago:
          print("True:  ", fname, " at ", mtime.strftime("%H:%M %m/%d/%Y"))
          shutil.move(path, dest)


def find_info(): #this first func. works fine.for root, dirs, files in os.walk(created):
  for root, dirs, files in os,walk(origin_path.get()):
      for fname in files:
          path = os.path.join(root, fname)
          st = os.stat(path)
          mtime = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(st.st_mtime)                          
  if mtime > ago:
      print(True)
  else:
      print(False)



print (find_info())                           
print (move())                               

print (os.listdir(dest))
print (os.listdir(created))

Here's the error:

C:/Users/quirk/PycharmProjects/Trial_2
C:/Users/quirk/PycharmProjects/Trial_2/.idea
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\quirk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
  return self.func(*args)
File "C:\Users\quirk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Projects\File_transfer.py", line 63, in <lambda>
  scan_btn=Button(text="Scan", command = lambda:submitFunction())
File "C:\Users\quirk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Projects\File_transfer.py", line 39, in submitFunction
  shutil.move(path, receiving_path)
File "C:\Users\quirk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\shutil.py", line 791, in move
  if os.path.isdir(dst):
File "C:\Users\quirk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\genericpath.py", line 42, in isdir
  st = os.stat(s)
TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not StringVar
```

Comment: It is similar issue as your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71096970/python-expecting-expected-str-bytes-or-os-pathlike-object-not-stringvar).  I wonder why you don't learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

As the message says, `receiving_path` is a `StringVar` object, not a string.  To fetch the string value, you need to use `.get()`:

```
          shutil.move(path, receiving_path.get())
```